# TSQL - Subquery filtering on multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, duplicates, subquery

Can a sub query that returns multiple values like this be performed to filter out duplicate values or is this type of sub-query invalid syntax?

```
SELECT AccountID, TransID 
FROM CardTrans 
WHERE (AccountID, CardAmount, CardDate) IN (
        SELECT AccountID, CardAmount, CardDate 
        FROM CardTrans 
        GROUP BY AccountID, CardAmount, CardDate 
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

I'm getting an error on line 3 stating: ***An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.***

Comment: the problem is not the subquery, but the fact that SQL Server doesn't allows a `WHERE (col1, col2, col3) IN .....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server does not support tuples with `in`.  Just use a `join`:

```
SELECT AccountID, TransID 
FROM CardTrans ct JOIN
     (SELECT AccountID, CardAmount, CardDate 
      FROM CardTrans 
      GROUP BY AccountID, CardAmount, CardDate 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) acc
     ON acc.AccountId = ct.AccountId AND acc.CardAmount = ct.CardAmount AND
        acc.CardDate = ct.CardDate;
```

Wait!  I notice this is all the same table.  Just use window functions:

```
select ct.AccountID, ct.TransID 
from (select ct.*,
             count(*) over (partition by AccountID, CardAmount, CardDate) as cnt
      from CardTrans ct
     ) ct
where cnt > 1;
```